# Google App Engine Upload Very Slow

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using the latest setup available, App Engine SDK 1.9, Eclipse Kepler, Java 7, When I try to deploy my web application I am getting the below,

------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\DOCUME~1\ameya\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg7431652405143311006.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Initiating update.
    Cloning 2 static files.
    Cloning 15 application files.

Deploying:
    Uploading 0 files.
    Initializing precompilation...
    Deploying new version.

Verifying availability:
    Will check again in 1 seconds.
    Will check again in 2 seconds.
    Will check again in 4 seconds.
    Will check again in 8 seconds.
    Will check again in 16 seconds.
    Will check again in 32 seconds.
    Will check again in 60 seconds.
    Will check again in 60 seconds.
    Will check again in 60 seconds.

The deployment just hangs. But after sometime it gets deployed, but it takes too much time, I have worked on very initial versions of the app engine and it used to work faster earlier.

It takes a very long time to deploy :(

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Ameya Beri

Answer (score 2):

The delay is probably caused by an unacknowledged temporary server condition.  It has happened previously and usually improves after a few hours.

Comment: Agree with Martin. In case you are interested. Additionally, there is also a System Status Dashboard (https://code.google.com/status/appengine) and an Atom Feed (https://code.google.com/status/appengine/alert_feed.xml) of the incidents.

Comment: Thanks Romin for the extra resource links.

Comment: Mine is constantly slow. I mean 20-minute slow, just creating the staging directory...on an SSD. App hasn't really grown in complexity, so likely some local condition.