# Deploying to App Engine: Verifying availability

Tags: google-app-engine

When I deploy my project to App Engine from Eclipse, the time it takes for "Veryfing availability" to finish varies a lot. Sometimes it just takes a couple of seconds, but mostly it looks like this:

```
Verifying availability:
Will check again in 1 seconds.
Will check again in 2 seconds.
Will check again in 4 seconds.
Will check again in 8 seconds.
Will check again in 16 seconds.
Will check again in 32 seconds.
Will check again in 60 seconds.
Will check again in 60 seconds.
Will check again in 60 seconds.
Will check again in 1 seconds.
Will check again in 2 seconds.
Will check again in 4 seconds.
Will check again in 8 seconds.
Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
```

What's happening during this process, and is there anything I can do to make it go away? It's a little frustrating when I only do small changes and have to wait for ages to test it.

Comment: I've been there and don't really know how to avoid this, but have you tried the development server? You run it locally and there is no deployment time. Maybe you should try it, specially if you are doing only small changes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the development server too, but I'm mainly developing a backend for a mobile app and have to deploy in order to test some of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That is some App Engine delay over which we have no control.  Just have to live with it.  It is some race to deploy on the servers where the GAE traffic cops are trying to get everyone's apps deployed, updated, and readied. Can be frustrating sometimes, but it's part of the deal.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22433405/1814970) answer (from the Java GAE):

> The delay is probably caused by an unacknowledged temporary server
>   condition. It has happened previously and usually improves after a few
>   hours.

[This resource](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/aMlt9uSzH_4) suggest the same.

From personal experience it indeed improves after a few hours.